# Initializing a delegate variable

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, nullpointerexception, delegates

I'm using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library to handle HTTP operations. I created a separate Java class called HttpClient to include all the methods that can be reused. I only implemented the method for a POST request so far.

```
public class HttpClient {

    private static final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    private static OnHttpRequestComplete listener;

    public static void post(String url, Map<String, String> postData) throws IOException {
        FormEncodingBuilder form = new FormEncodingBuilder();
        for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : postData.entrySet()) {
            form.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        RequestBody body = form.build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                listener.requestFailed(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Response: " + jsonObj.toString());
                        listener.requestSuccessful();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        listener.requestFailed(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

interface OnHttpRequestComplete {
    public void requestSuccessful();
    public void requestFailed(Exception e);
}
```

Now since I'd be calling these methods from other classes, I need a way to send back the data I get. And because the execution is done asynchronously, I can't have the methods to simply return the values. I come from iOS so I thought this would be a good place to make use of the delegate pattern.

I did some research and found out that delegates are called interfaces in Java. So I added an interface called `OnHttpRequestComplete` with two methods, `requestSuccessful()` and `requestFailed(Exception e)`. I also declared a variable at the top of the HttpClient class called `listener` of type `OnHttpRequestComplete`.

In a separate Activity, I implement these two methods and ran the app. The http request is fired and gets the response successfully. But as soon as it hits the line `listener.requestSuccessful();`, the app crashes with a NullPointerException. I assume it's because the `listener` variable is not initialized. But I can't figure out how to do that.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The problem is that you still need to set your listener interface. This can be done either by passing an instance of `OnHttpRequestComplete` through your constructor or using an explicit setter.

Comment: where do you set the listener?

Comment: @hoomi Yes! I added a explicit setter and it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `List<OnHttpRequestComplete> listeners` instead because you probably want to be able to have multiple subscribers to your event.

```
private static List<OnHttpRequestComplete> listeners;

public HttpClient() {
    listeners = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addListener(OnHttpRequestComplete listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}

public void removeListener(OnHttpRequestComplete listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener);
}
```

When you are done, you call a callback method this way:

```
for (OnHttpRequestComplete listener : listeners) {
    listener.requestSuccessful();
}
```

In your activity, call `addListener` in `onResume` and `removeListener` in `onPause` to avoid memory leaks.